# js не добавляется класс . Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: mainBtn.addEventListener is not a function at script.js:65

Tags: javascript

js

```
let mainBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn__main');

if(window.innerWidth >= 800){
mainBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        for( let i = 0; i < mainBtn.length; i++){
            mainBtn[i].classList.add('hover__main__btn');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` говорит о том, что он собирает коллекцию элементов (то есть *много*/*несколько*). У самой коллекции нет такого метода, а вот у элементов коллекции - есть.

Если на странице только один элемент с таким классом, то стоит воспользоваться методом `querySelector`. Если так хочется именно этот метод, тогда придётся привязывать слушателя у первого элемента коллекции

```
mainBtn[0].addEventListener
```

А если элементов много, то тогда слушатель навешивается в цикле, как это было сделано ниже `mainBtn[i].classList`. То есть скорее всего будет так:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mainBtn.length; i++){
    mainBtn[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){        
        mainBtn[i].classList.add('hover__main__btn');        
    });
}
```